# Application opens twice when file specified

Tags: terminal, applications, file

Typing `open -a emacs` opens one window.  Fine.
Typing `open -a emacs foo.txt` opens *two* windows, one as above, and one with `foo.txt` in it.

Why is that and what should I do to fix it?

Answer (score 2):

You have to enclose the document you're trying to open in quotes

```
open -a emacs "/foo/bar/foobar.txt"
```